# Convert From Hijri to Georgian date in ASP & C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date-conversion

I have two text boxes, One in **Hijri Date** which I am inserting date in this text box using the calender extender. What I want is that upon selection of date (Hijri Date), the Georgian text box will filled with converted  Georgian  date using C#.

Does anyone has code for changing the hijri date to georgian date?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply convert between Hijri and Gregorian using the built in CultureInfo class

```
Imports System.Globalization

Private Sub Convert_From_Hijri_To_Gregorian(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim arCI As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("ar-SA")
    Dim hijri As String = Me.TextBox1.Text   '//check if string is valid date first

    Dim tempDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(hijri, "dd/MM/yyyy", arCI.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite)
    Me.TextBox2.Text = tempDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

End Sub
```

I am not a C# guy but here is my the conversion of the above code to C#

```
using System.Globalization;

private void Convert_From_Hijri_To_Gregorian(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo arCI = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
    string hijri = TextBox1.Text;

    DateTime tempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(hijri, "dd/MM/yyyy", arCI.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite);
    TextBox2.Text = tempDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");


}
```

I have written this code after reading [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8838/Convert-date-from-Hijri-Calendar-to-Gregorian-Cale) article

Comment: Note that link-only answers are strongly discouraged on SO. Answer should be final destination in search of a solution.

Comment: @mvp : thanks for the kind notification. Will keep that in mind next time.