# string was not recognized as a valid datetime while Converting Date from Hijri to Gregorian date

Tags: c#, datetime

I am Trying to Convert Hijri Date into Gregorian Date I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751763/convert-from-hijri-to-georgian-date-in-asp-c) article and My Code is as follows :

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-sa");
string date = "19/12/36 12:00:00 ص";
```

Getting

> string was not recognized as a valid datetime

error in below line

```
DateTime tempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite);
lblDate.Text = tempDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I am getting string was not recognized as a valid datetime. Please can somebody tell me whats wrong with this code?

Comment: @TimSchmelter language is "ar-sa"

Comment: In the 2nd line of your code what's this character `ص`?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8838/Convert-date-from-Hijri-Calendar-to-Gregorian-Cale

Comment: It is a time that I am recieving  in Hijri "19/12/36 12:00:00 ص" so I need to convert it in Gregorian. May be it's Hijri Format but i am not sure.

Comment: Are you sure this `19/12/36` is valid `DateTime` for `UmAlQuraCalendar` which is used by `ar-sa` culture? Because from [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/umalquracalendar.cs,13) it says: `MinDate` is `1318/01/01` which is equal to `1900/04/30` in Gregorian and `MaxDate` is `1500/12/30` which is equal to `2077/11/17` in Gregorian. Since it's `TwoDigitYearMax` property is `1451`, your `36` will be parsed as `1436` even if you use `yy` format. I honestly little bit confused.

Comment: @SonerGönül Actually I am getting this time format from Sharepoint 2013 arabic site so I think you are right the real time is 19/12/1436 12:00:00 ص but unfortunately I am getting only 19/12/36 12:00:00 ص so I have to work on this input :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'm on the right way but.. Let's try something at least.

First of all, `DateTime` values are *always* in the Gregorian calendar, basically. There's no such thing as "A `DateTime` in a [`UmAlQuraCalendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar.aspx) calendar" - which is used by `ar-sa` culture - you *have to* use the `UmAlQuraCalendar` to interpret a `DateTime` in a particular way.

Second, when you use `DateTime.ParseExact` for parsing your string, your string and format does match **exactly** based on culture you use. Since `ص`
character seems [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator.aspx) of `ar-sa` culture, you should provide `tt` specifier with your time part as well.

```
string s = "19/12/36 12:00:00 ص";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-sa"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Note: Since [`TwoDigitYearMax`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx) is `1451` of `UmAlQuraCalendar` calendar, your `36` will be parsed as `1436` with `yy` format specifier.

This perfectly parse your question but **WAIT!** What will be the result? Here it is.

```
02/10/2015 00:00:00
```

Why? As I said in the top, you **have to** use the `UmAlQuraCalendar` to interpret this `DateTime` instance.

```
UmAlQuraCalendar ul = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
Console.WriteLine(ul.GetYear(dt)); // 1436
Console.WriteLine(ul.GetMonth(dt)); // 12
Console.WriteLine(ul.GetDayOfMonth(dt)); // 19
```